# How can I select the first and second to last record for a given group in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata I need to select the first record for a group as well as the second to last record for the same group for multiple groups with other set conditions. How can I acheive this?

ex table:

| group id | records | date | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| One | 2 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| One | 3 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| One | 4 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| One | 1 | 2022-01-12 | 2 |
| Two | 1 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 2 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 3 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 4 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 5 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 6 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 5 | 2022-05-12 | 1 |
| Two | 6 | 2022-05-12 | 1 |

Desired Output:

| group id | records | date | place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| One | 3 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 1 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |
| Two | 5 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |

Comment: What are the "other set conditions"?

Comment: what are you sorting by to get "first" and "second to last"?

Comment: Is the "Records" column always numbered sequentually 1 thru max? Do the same "groups" always share the same date as depicted? Can "second to last" be the same as "first" with a group of only 2 rows? Is "Place" relevant?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
select
*
from
table
qualify row_number() over (partition by groupid order by date ASC) = 1 --"first"
or  row_number() over (partition by groupid order by date DESC) = 2 -- "second to last"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested,  just an idea.

```
select q.*
from
(
select t.*,
max(t.records)-1 over (partition by t.group_id) as mxprev
from yourtable as t
) as q
where q.records=1 or q.records=q.mxprev
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you're ok with specifying each group manually:

```
(SELECT * FROM extable 
WHERE groupid = 'One'
ORDER BY date ASC -- or whatever you want to order by to get "first" and "second to last" 
LIMIT 1) 

UNION 

(SELECT * FROM extable 
WHERE groupid = 'One'
ORDER BY date DESC -- or whatever you want to order by to get "first" and "second to last"
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1)

UNION 

(SELECT * FROM extable 
WHERE groupid = 'Two'
ORDER BY date ASC -- or whatever you want to order by to get "first" and "second to last" 
LIMIT 1) 

UNION 

(SELECT * FROM extable 
WHERE groupid = 'Two'
ORDER BY date DESC -- or whatever you want to order by to get "first" and "second to last"
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET 1);
```

(looking into a more generic solution atm)

Answer (score 0):

Should work , not tested

```
select * from 
  (select *
   ,row_number() over(partition by group id order by records) rn1
   from table1
  ) t1 where t1 = 1
union all
select * from 
(
   select *
    ,row_number() over(partition by group id order by records desc) rn2
   from table1
) t2 where  rn2 = 2
```